# PHP curl_init(), curl_exec() work from the command line but fail when browsed/accessed from a webserver

Tags: php, apache-2.4, php-fpm, curl

The following PHP script (when not anonymized) runs successfully at the commandline. It uses curl_init() and curl_exec() to retrieve JSON-formatted data, converts the result into an associative array, and displays a particular array value.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$url = "https://host.ext";
$user = "<user>";
$pass = "<pw>";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user.":".$pass);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));

$result = curl_exec($curl);
$resultlen = strlen($result);

curl_close($curl);

$r_ary = array();
$r_ary = json_decode( $result , true , 512 , JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY );
$st = 'status';
$status = $r_ary[$st];

echo "<!doctype html>";
echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
   echo "Length: $resultlen";
   echo "Status: $status";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

It retrieves 913 characters of data, and produces the output:

```
[root@box local]# ./test.php 
<!doctype html><html><body>Length: 913Status: active</body></html>
[root@box local]#
```

But, if I remove the initial "#!..." line, place the result in my web server's document root, and browse the file I get zero bytes retrieved:
[image: Zero Length]

I get the same result accessing test.php via a calling script from elsewhere on the local LAN:

```
[root@box2 work23]$ 
[root@box2 work23]$ cat call.php
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$webPage = "http://box/test.php";
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$fd = fopen($webPage, "r");
$r = file_get_contents( $webPage );
print "Retrieved: $r \n";
fclose($fd);
?>

[root@box2 work23]$ ./call.php 
Retrieved: <!doctype html><html><body>Length: 0Status: </body></html>
 

[root@box2 work23]$
```

Commenting/Uncommenting different combinations of the RETURNTRANSFER and HTTPHEADER options has no effect on the webserver version, but the commandline version needs the RETURNTRANSFER option to work. The system is Centos Stream 9, running apache 2.4.57 with php-fpm rather than mod_php. The PHP interpreter is version 8.0.30. I experience the same issue on an AlmaLinux system of similar vintage.

```
[root@box local]# apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.57 (CentOS Stream)
Server built:   Jul 20 2023 00:00:00
[root@box local]# uname -a
Linux box 5.14.0-402.el9.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Dec 21 19:46:35 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@box local]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Stream release 9
[root@box local]#
```

The logs in /var/log/php-fpm aren't especially illuminating, but they do show that none of the curl_xxx() functions generate errors, it just seems that curl_exec() returns no data:

```
[root@box php-fpm]# pwd
/var/log/php-fpm
[root@box php-fpm]# ls -l
total 8
-rw-------. 1 root   root   2160 Jan  5 15:48 error.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache 4003 Jan  5 17:08 www-error.log
[root@box php-fpm]# tail -3 www-error.log 
[05-Jan-2024 22:05:12 UTC] PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /var/www/html/test.php on line 25
[05-Jan-2024 22:08:57 UTC] PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /var/www/html/test.php on line 25
[05-Jan-2024 22:08:57 UTC] PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /var/www/html/test.php on line 25
[root@box php-fpm]# tail error.log 
[04-Jan-2024 00:18:23] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[04-Jan-2024 00:18:23] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[04-Jan-2024 13:21:25] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1056
[04-Jan-2024 13:21:25] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[04-Jan-2024 13:21:25] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[05-Jan-2024 01:08:01] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[05-Jan-2024 01:08:01] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[05-Jan-2024 15:48:49] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1055
[05-Jan-2024 15:48:49] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[05-Jan-2024 15:48:49] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[root@box php-fpm]#
```

I installed httpd, php, php-fpm and their prerequisites via dnf. I can't find a whole lot of info on php-fpm and how to configure it. I found the files /etc/php-fpm.conf and /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf, but they had no references to curl. There is only one php.ini file, in /etc.

If anyone has encountered and resolved this issue, your help would be much appreciated. The httpd configuration files indicate that it might be possible to switch from php-fpm to mod_php. I may try that, if mod_php is still available anyplace.

Answer (score 1):

It develops that my problem was something I should've considered much sooner than I finally did: selinux. Whenever there is no good reason for something to not work, but it still insists on not working, there is a good chance that selinux and/or firewalld are at least part of the problem.

The default selinux policies for httpd frown upon web documents opening any sort of new file/stream, including connections to other websites. To get the PHP script to work with selinux enabled I had to toggle two selinux booleans:

```
[root@arch php-fpm]# setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
[root@arch php-fpm]# setsebool -P httpd_unified 1
```

And then restart httpd.

After that, the web version of my PHP script's curl_exec() call was able to retrieve the same data as when I ran the script from the command line.